# Auto Update Stats From SQL Database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get an effect like the http://www.minecraft.net page where it auto updates sales from a database, I've been researching this for two months now and no luck. 
I have a php file which finds how many results are in a database and displays them as a number, works fine http://tzeale.com/sandbox/stats/pull.php

What I'm trying to do is get the effect like minecraft.net where it auto updates without refreshing the page. Could anyone guide me on what to  do? I don't know what else to try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hYou need to use AJAX.

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), alongside a AJAX call to that pull.php

If you are using jQuery, here is a good example on how to achieve what you want.
Added a simple logic to see if the server is dead, and eventually stop.

```
var failed = 0; 
var limit_failed = 5;
(function updateSales( waitTime ){
   waitTime = waitTime || 1000; // Set to 1 second by default

   setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: 'pull.php',
           success: function( response ){
               // Update something with your response
                alert ("sales are now at: "+ response);
               updateSales(); // Recursion
           },
           error: function(){           
                // Error handling - not necessary
               // If the request failed more then (limit_failed) times, you might want to stop it from checking after (limit_failed) times, 
               // and in the meanwhile icnrease the wait time, so the server has more time to get back online.
               if( ++failed < limit_failed ){
                   waitTime += 1000;
                   updateSales( waitTime );
               }
           }
       });
   }, waitTime);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `setTimeout` and Ajax.  setTimeout would get the data every 1000 ms (or however you set it) using Ajax to get the data.

You would wrap your display count in your `html` like this for example:

```
<span id="mycount"></span>
```

Then your jQuery code would look something like this:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
   $.get("/sandbox/stats/pull.php",function(data){
      $("#mycount").html(data);
   });
 },1000);
```

`1000` is one second, you can change it if you'd like.  I don't know how to make it animate like that, but it would go inside your `$.get()` function once you retreive the data.  Also this must be on the same domain as `http://tzeale.com/` for the Ajax to work due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

---

**HOWEVER**, After reviewing te minecraft.net site, I noticed they are loading this data into their page one time, instead of getting it every 1 second:

```
<script>
var justLoggedIn = false;
var totalUsers = 33652552;
var paidUsers = 6495707;
var totalUsersRate = 1.2166667;
var paidUsersRate = 0.15;
</script>
```

Then they are not getting live data with this.  They are just getting the current amount, then keep adding 1 to it.

They make it animate using this plugin: http://timeago.yarp.com/
And still using `setTimeout()` to keep adding 1 to it every second. I don't think this is real users, just a counter starting at the `var totalUsers`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for nearly three months now! :D